# How to store multiple python gui tools at one place in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, web, pyqt4

i have built a few tools using PyQt4 in python. Now i want them to store on single web interface for easy accessing at one place. I am using django for web interface. But i don't know any way how to put these tools in django or any other web interface.
can anyone tell me anyway to do this ?

Comment: have you tried some code?

Comment: yes i have build server using django, i want to add these tool on this server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does not support gui so I can't store multiple python gui tools at one place. Although I used html and css in front end in place of gui. this has resolved my problem.